# Save Response from Server using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form which act like a multi submit .So first time when i am going to submit the form `btnCount=0`.When i click the submit button `btnCount` will increment.and each time i will get response from server after submit .so i want to save the response using an hook and later display it as a table so i did this

```
const [listaddress, SetlistAddress] = useState([
    {
      agyAddrTypeCode: "",
      agyId: "",
      addressId:""
      

    },
  ]);
const submitEachAddress =(inputs,btnCount)=>
  {
    setbtnCount(btnCount + 1);
      const response = axios.post(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVICE_URL + "/addresses",
      inputs
    ).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        //let listaddress = [...response.data];
        listaddress[btnCount]['agyAddrTypeCode'] =response.data.addrType;
       
     
      }
      console.log(listaddress);
     
    });;
   

  }
```

But got an error

> uncaught in promise cannot set properties of undefined setting
> agyAddrTypeCode

Expected output:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{agyAddrTypeCode: 1}
1
: 
{agyAddrTypeCode: 2}
2
: 
{agyAddrTypeCode: 3}
length
: 
3
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

but its work for me when button count is 0.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is button count? This will crash if it is ever different from 0, since there is only one element in your addresses list

Comment: `agyAddrTypeCode` is undefined when count > 0, that's because `listaddress` is an array, and initilized with only one item in it. You need to push a new object to it using `SetlistAddress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is from btnCount state. the problem is from just having one item in initial value of listaddress and when btnCount change to 1, so in listaddress  index 1 is `undefined` and it will throw `uncaught in promise cannot set properties of undefined setting agyAddrTypeCode` error.

And you cannot assign state directly like this `listaddress[btnCount]['agyAddrTypeCode'] =response.data.addrType;` you need to use setter.

I reorganized your code for handling it.

```
 const submitEachAddress = (inputs) => {
  const response = axios
    .post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVICE_URL + '/addresses', inputs)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.status);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        SetlistAddress([...listaddress,{
          agyAddrTypeCode : response.data.addrType;
        }])
        setbtnCount(prevState => prevState + 1);
      }
      console.log(listaddress);
    });
};
```